# I don't understand why my Do-While loop will not terminate

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I want my program to print outputs until the user types "bye". However, when I type "bye" the loop/program does not stop. Here is the method:

```
public static void startConversation(ChattyBot chatty) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = myScanner.nextLine();
    do
    {
         System.out.println(chatty.getResponse(userInput));
         userInput = myScanner.nextLine();
    }
    while (!(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))); 
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. What is `chatty`?

Comment: A guess, you're creating multiple Scanner objects based on `System.in`, and this may be closing your standard input. You should only create **one** single such Scanner object and share it around in your program.

Comment: You take input before the loop, then take more input in the loop, totally ignoring the first input

Comment: remove this line from your code  **String userInput = myScanner.nextLine();** and simple define String with any value or null. It will work

Comment: The most likely explanation is that there is no input on `System.in`.  But we can't help you debug this unless you provide a proper MVCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try while loop

```
while(!(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")))  {
         System.out.println(chatty.getResponse(userInput));
         userInput = myScanner.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your code, if user input `"bye"` as soon as application started, it will not work because of `scanner.next()` line of code outside of the loop. After the first input your program will work fine. To fix this, simply remove the `scanner.next()` entry outside of the loop.

```
public static void startConversation(ChattyBot chatty) {
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput;
do
{
     userInput = myScanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println(chatty.getResponse(userInput));
}
while (!(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))); 
}
```

Comment: He is calling method `chatty.getResponse(userInput)` before input in your code so this will not work

Comment: Again this will not work because if he types `"bye"` method will be called

Comment: Just saw it myself before your comment. So I made a edit.

Comment: I beleive, that could be the intended behavior. User might need to output something before exit.

Comment: In my opinion from what i understand program needs to end after typing “bye” without calling method